# Element name 'test_depend' is invalid. ROS2

Tags: ros, ros2

The problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qG6xc.png

I'm following a ROS2 course online but in my case, there is a problem that in the video doesn't appear. In the course is used ROS2 Humble while I use ROS2 Iron

I asked ChatGPT and it told me to move the tags <build_depend>, <exec_depend> and <member_of_group> into the .

Comment: You should post ROS questions over at the robotics site: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/